# YouTube com eventos do Analytics

Tags: javascript, youtube, google-analytics-api

Estou usando o seguinte esquema para embutir os vídeos do Youtube:
https://jsfiddle.net/4qcr60xz/

Isso permite que o vídeo só seja solicitado no momento em que o usuário clica no "player" (thumbnail), fazendo com que a página carregue mais rápido.

Preciso adicionar um acompanhamento de evento do Google Analytics para quando o usuário clicar no "play/thumbnail" que renderiza o iframe do vídeo.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Video1');
```

Existe uma forma de implementarmos isso a esse código do jsfiddle?

Comment: Não usamos "Resolvido" aqui Diego. Caso uma resposta resolva sua questão marque-a como correta. Saiba mais fazendo o [tour]. :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUÇÃO:**

```
document.querySelector(".youtube-player").addEventListener("click",function(){
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Video1');
});
```